# Cauchy Schwarz Inequality Proof

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help to show that
 $$(\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^2)(\sum
_{i=1}^n |b_i|^2)- |\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i|^2 =  \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_k \bar a_k b_j \bar b_j- a_k \bar a_jb_i \bar b_j)$$
Or more so because i can do the algebra, an explanation on where the $\sum_{j=1}^n$ appeared.

Comment: Because when you put the two summations together, the indices don't have to be the same. So you need to change one of them to another variable $j$.

Comment: @KittyL is that something I need to prove in my proof or that goes without saying? Additionally, does this same idea apply for a summation of n terms * a summation of k terms = summation of n terms * summation of n terms?

Answer (score 0):

We have

\begin{align}&\sum_{i = 1}^n |a_i|^2 \sum_{i = 1}^n |b_i|^2 - \left|\sum_{i = 1}^na_ib_i\right|^2\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n |a_i|^2 |b_j|^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^n a_ib_i \overline{\sum_{j = 1}^n a_jb_j}\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n |a_i|^2 |b_j|^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^n a_ib_i\sum_{j = 1}^n \bar{a_j}\bar{b_j}\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n a_i\bar{a_i} b_j\bar{b_j} - \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n a_ib_i\bar{a_j}\bar{b_j}\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n (a_i\bar{a_i}b_j\bar{b_j} - a_i\bar{a_j}b_i\bar{b_j}).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

This is to explain the question of summation in the comment.

It doesn't have to be proved. Consider this:

$$\sum^n_{i=1} a_i \sum^n_{i=1} b_i=(a_1+...a_n)(b_1+...b_n)\\=a_1b_1+a_1b_2+...a_1b_n+a_2b_1+......+a_nb_n\\
=\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}a_ib_j$$

However,

$$\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{i=1}a_ib_i=\sum^n_{i=1}(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...a_nb_n)=n(a_1b_1+...a_nb_n)$$